# write data column wise in a MongoDB document

Tags: python, excel, mongodb, selenium, web-scraping

I have made a scraper which scrapes data from a website. My code as of now writes in an excel file. It also reads and updates the excel file. My code first reads the excel database to make sure it updates the present information in the excel sheet and if there is some new information in the website which is not in the excel database, it is added to the sheet.

Following is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from selenium import webdriver
import time 
import pandas as pd
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from xlrd import open_workbook
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import logging


#make lists for all the different aspects needed.
links = []
pics = []
types = []
names = []
descs = []
views = []
no_speakers = []
location = []
dates = []
people = []
organization = [] 
summ = []
twitter = []
facebook = []
contact = []
emails = []
website_link = []
venue = []
official_address = []
speakers  = []
fees = []
at_tr = []
prev_links = []
index = -1
update = []

def main_url(url):
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
    driver.get(url) #gets the URL
    time.sleep(5) # wait 5 seconds until DOM will load completly
    while True:
        try:
            driver.find_element_by_id('view_more').click() #clicks on load more until there are no more events to be loaded. 
            time.sleep(3)
        except Exception as e:
            break

    rows = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('sec_conf_main')
    for row in rows:
        conf = row.find_element_by_class_name('conf_summery')
        nam = conf.find_element_by_class_name('c_name')
        name = nam.find_element_by_tag_name('a')

        if len(names) != 0 and name.get_attribute('title') in names:
            index = names.index(name.get_attribute('title'))

            pic = row.find_element_by_class_name('conf_logo')
            link = pic.find_element_by_tag_name('a')
            if links[index] == link:
                pass
            else:
                links[index] = link.get_attribute('href') #get link of event.
                if not link.get_attribute('href') in update:
                    update.append(link.get_attribute('href'))

            img = link.find_element_by_tag_name('img')
            if pics[index] == img.get_attribute('src'):
                pass
            else:
                pics[index] = img.get_attribute('src') #picture source of event.
                if not link.get_attribute('href') in update:
                    update.append(link.get_attribute('href'))

            desc = row.find_element_by_class_name('conf_desc')
            if descs[index] == desc.text:
                pass
            else:
                descs[index] = desc.text #description of event.
                if not link.get_attribute('href') in update:
                    update.append(link.get_attribute('href'))

            d = conf.find_elements_by_tag_name('strong')
            count = 0
            while count < len(d):
                view = d[count].text
                if views[index] == view:
                    pass
                else:
                    views[index] = view #number of views. 
                    if not link.get_attribute('href') in update:
                        update.append(link.get_attribute('href'))

                if no_speakers[index] == d[count + 1].text:
                    pass
                else:
                    no_speakers[index] = d[count + 1].text #number of speakers. 
                    if not link.get_attribute('href') in update:
                        update.append(link.get_attribute('href'))
                count = count +  2

            t = conf.find_elements_by_class_name('spel')
            ty = []
            for item in t:
                ty.append(item.get_attribute('title'))
            if types[index] == ','.join(ty):
                pass
            else:
                types[index] = (','.join(ty))#speciality of event. 
                if not link.get_attribute('href') in update:
                    update.append(link.get_attribute('href'))

            date_place = conf.find_elements_by_class_name('c_summery')
            for item in date_place:
                try:
                    if item.find_element_by_tag_name('img'):
                        if location[index] == item.text:
                            pass
                        else:
                            location[index] = (item.text) #location of event 
                            if not link.get_attribute('href') in update:
                                update.append(link.get_attribute('href'))
                except NoSuchElementException as e:
                    pass
                try:
                    if item.find_element_by_tag_name('span'):
                        date = item.text
                        i = date.find('|')
                        if dates[index] == date[:i]:
                            pass
                        else:
                            dates[index] = (date[:i]) #date from and to of event. 
                            if not link.get_attribute('href') in update:
                                update.append(link.get_attribute('href'))
                except NoSuchElementException as e:
                    pass

        else:
            names.append(name.get_attribute('title')) #title of event.
            pic = row.find_element_by_class_name('conf_logo')
            link = pic.find_element_by_tag_name('a')
            links.append(link.get_attribute('href')) #get link of event. 

            img = link.find_element_by_tag_name('img')
            pics.append(img.get_attribute('src')) #picture source of event.

            desc = row.find_element_by_class_name('conf_desc')
            descs.append(desc.text) #description of event. 

            d = conf.find_elements_by_tag_name('strong')
            count = 0
            while count < len(d):
                view = d[count].text
                views.append(view) #number of views. 
                no_speakers.append(d[count + 1].text) #number of speakers. 
                count = count +  2

            t = conf.find_elements_by_class_name('spel')
            ty = []
            for item in t:
                ty.append(item.get_attribute('title'))
            types.append(','.join(ty))#speciality of event. 

            date_place = conf.find_elements_by_class_name('c_summery')
            for item in date_place:
                try:
                    if item.find_element_by_tag_name('img'):
                        location.append(item.text) #location of event 
                except NoSuchElementException as e:
                    pass
                try:
                    if item.find_element_by_tag_name('span'):
                        date = item.text
                        index = date.find('|')
                        dates.append(date[:index]) #date from and to of event. 
                except NoSuchElementException as e:
                    pass

    driver.close()
    driver.quit()

def each_event(item):
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
    try:
        driver.get(item) #get each Link of the event. 
        time.sleep(5)
        if len(prev_links) != 0 and item in prev_links:
            index = links.index(item)

            try:
                org = driver.find_element_by_class_name('speakers')
                l = org.text.split()
                if organization[index] == ' '.join(l[3:]):
                    pass
                else:
                    organization[index] = (' '.join(l[3:]))
                    if not item in update:
                        update.append(item)
            except NoSuchElementException as e:
                organization[index] = 'No Organization Given.'

            try:
                summary = driver.find_element_by_class_name('conf_head_summary')
                if summ[index] == summary.find_element_by_tag_name('p').text:
                    pass
                else:
                    summ[index] = (summary.find_element_by_tag_name('p').text)
                    if not item in update:
                        update.append(item)
            except NoSuchElementException as e:
                summ[index] = 'No Conference Summary Given.'

            try:
                tw = driver.find_element_by_class_name('TW')
                if twitter[index] == tw.get_attribute('title'):
                    pass
                else:
                    twitter[index] = (tw.get_attribute('title'))
                    if not item in update:
                        update.append(item)
            except NoSuchElementException as e:
                twitter[index] = 'No Twitter Link'

            try:
                fb = driver.find_element_by_class_name('FB')
                if facebook[index] == fb.get_attribute('title'):
                    pass
                else:
                    facebook[index] = (fb.get_attribute('title'))
                    if not item in update:
                        update.append(item)
            except NoSuchElementException as e:
                facebook[index] = ('No Facebook Link')

            try:
                c = driver.find_element_by_class_name('marB20').find_element_by_xpath('//table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]').text
                if contact[index] == c:
                    pass
                else:
                    if len(c) == 0:
                        contact[index] = ('No Contact Number Given.')
                    else:
                        contact[index] = (c)
                        if not item in update:
                            update.append(item)
            except NoSuchElementException as e:
                contact[index] = ('No Contact Number Given.')

            try:
                email = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('emailFruser')
                e = []
                for item in email:
                    e.append(item.text)
                if emails[index] == ','.join(e):
                    pass
                else:
                    emails[index] = (','.join(e))
                    if not item in update:
                        update.append(item)
            except NoSuchElementException as e:
                emails[index] = ('No email.')

            try:
                web = driver.find_element_by_id('cRegistraionpopup5').get_attribute('href')
                if website_link[index] == web:
                    pass
                else:
                    website_link[index] = (web)
                    if not item in update:
                        update.append(item)
            except NoSuchElementException as e:
                website_link[index] = ('No Website Link')

            try:
                v = driver.find_element_by_class_name('conf_venue1').text
                if venue[index] == v:
                    pass
                else:
                    venue[index] = (v)
                    if not item in update:
                        update.append(item)
            except NoSuchElementException as e:
                venue[index] = ('No Venue Given.')

            try:
                oa = driver.find_element_by_class_name('hotel-detail').text
                if official_address[index] == oa:
                    pass
                else:
                    official_address[index] = oa
                    if not item in update:
                        update.append(item)
            except NoSuchElementException as e:
                official_address[index] = ('No Official Address Given. ')

            try:
                sp = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('speaker_single_inn')
                l = []
                for item in sp:
                    l.append(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div/h5/a').text)
                if len(l) == 0:
                    speakers[index] = 'No Speakers'      

                if speakers[index] == ','.join(l):
                    pass
                else:
                    speakers[index] = (','.join(l))
                    if not item in update:
                        update.append(item)
            except NoSuchElementException as e:
                speakers[index] = ('No Speakers')

            try:
                s = driver.find_element_by_class_name('mobScroll')
                trs = s.find_elements_by_xpath('//table/tbody/tr')
                l = []
                for item in trs:
                    try:
                        item.find_element_by_class_name('ticketname_inn')
                        l.append(item.text)
                    except NoSuchElementException as e:
                        pass
                if fees[index] == ','.join(l):
                    pass
                else:
                    fees[index] = (';'.join(l))
                    if not item in update:
                        update.append(item)
            except NoSuchElementException as e:
                fees[index] = ('No Fees Given')

            try:
                sp = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('r-speaker-info')
                l = []
                for item in sp:
                    l.append(item.text)
                if len(l) == 0:
                    at_tr[index] = 'No Attenders or Trackers Given.'
                if at_tr[index] == ','.join(l):
                    pass
                else:
                    at_tr[index] = (','.join(l))
                    if not item in update:
                        update.append(item)
            except NoSuchElementException as e:
                at_tr[index] = ('No Attenders or Trackers Given')

        else:
            try:
                org = driver.find_element_by_class_name('speakers')
                l = org.text.split()
                organization.append(' '.join(l[3:]))
            except NoSuchElementException as e:
                organization.append('No Organization Given.')

            try:
                summary = driver.find_element_by_class_name('conf_head_summary')
                summ.append(summary.find_element_by_tag_name('p').text)
            except NoSuchElementException as e:
                summ.append('No Conference Summary Given.')

            try:
                tw = driver.find_element_by_class_name('TW')
                twitter.append(tw.get_attribute('title'))
            except:
                twitter.append('No Twitter Link')

            try:
                fb = driver.find_element_by_class_name('FB')
                facebook.append(fb.get_attribute('title'))
            except:
                facebook.append('No Facebook Link')

            try:
                c = driver.find_element_by_class_name('marB20').find_element_by_xpath('//table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]').text
                if len(c) == 0:
                    contact.append('No Contact Number Given.')
                else:
                    contact.append(c)
            except NoSuchElementException as e:
                contact.append('No Contact Number Given.')

            try:
                email = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('emailFruser')
                e = []
                for item in email:
                    e.append(item.text)
                emails.append(' '.join(e))
            except NoSuchElementException as e:
                emails.append('No email.')

            try:
                website_link.append(driver.find_element_by_id('cRegistraionpopup5').get_attribute('href'))
            except NoSuchElementException as e:
                website_link.append('No Website Link')

            try:
                venue.append(driver.find_element_by_class_name('conf_venue1').text)
            except NoSuchElementException as e:
                venue.append('No Venue Given.')

            try:
                official_address.append(driver.find_element_by_class_name('hotel-detail').text)
            except NoSuchElementException as e:
                official_address.append('No Official Address Given. ')

            try:
                sp = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('speaker_single_inn')
                l = []
                for item in sp:
                    l.append(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div/h5/a').text)
                if len(l) == 0:
                    speakers.append('No Speakers Given.')
                else:
                    speakers.append(','.join(l))
            except NoSuchElementException as e:
                speakers.append('No Speakers')

            try:
                s = driver.find_element_by_class_name('mobScroll')
                trs = s.find_elements_by_xpath('//table/tbody/tr')
                l = []
                for item in trs:
                    try:
                        item.find_element_by_class_name('ticketname_inn')
                        l.append(item.text)
                    except NoSuchElementException as e:
                        pass
                fees.append(';'.join(l))
            except NoSuchElementException as e:
                fees.append('No Fees Given')

            try:
                sp = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('r-speaker-info')
                l = []
                for item in sp:
                    l.append(item.text)
                if len(l) == 0:
                    at_tr.append('No Attenders or Trackers Given')
                else:
                    at_tr.append(','.join(l))
            except NoSuchElementException as e:
                at_tr.append('No Attenders or Trackers Given')

        driver.close()
        driver.quit()
    except Exception as e:
        pass

def main():
    file = 'EMedEvents.xlsx' #file to write in
    book = open_workbook(file)
    sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)

    d = pd.read_excel(file)
    if d.empty:
        pass
    else:
        for row in range(1, sheet.nrows):
            names.append(sheet.cell(row, 0).value)
            dates.append(sheet.cell(row, 1).value)
            types.append(sheet.cell(row, 2).value)
            location.append(sheet.cell(row, 3).value)
            descs.append(sheet.cell(row, 4).value)
            views.append(sheet.cell(row, 5).value)
            no_speakers.append(sheet.cell(row, 6).value)
            pics.append(sheet.cell(row, 7).value)
            links.append(sheet.cell(row, 8).value)
            organization.append(sheet.cell(row, 9).value)
            summ.append(sheet.cell(row, 10).value)
            twitter.append(sheet.cell(row, 11).value)
            facebook.append(sheet.cell(row, 12).value)
            contact.append(sheet.cell(row, 13).value)
            emails.append(sheet.cell(row, 14).value)
            website_link.append(sheet.cell(row, 15).value)
            venue.append(sheet.cell(row, 16).value)
            official_address.append(sheet.cell(row, 17).value)
            speakers.append(sheet.cell(row, 18).value)
            fees.append(sheet.cell(row, 19).value)
            at_tr.append(sheet.cell(row, 20).value)

    if len(links) != 0:
        for item in links:
            prev_links.append(item)

    main_url("https://www.emedevents.com/india-medical-conferences") #main url to use. 
    for item in links:
        each_event(item) #get people information of each event. 

    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Event Name':names,'Event Dates':dates, 'Specialty' : types,'Event Location' : location, 'Description' : descs, 
                                 'Views' : views, 'Speakers' : no_speakers, 'Picture Source' : pics, 'Event Link' : links, 'Organized By' : organization, 
                                 'Conference Summary' : summ, 'Twitter Link' : twitter, 'Facebook Link' : facebook,'Contact Number' : contact, 
                                 'Email' : emails, 'Website Link' : website_link, 'Venue' : venue, 'Official Address' : official_address, 'Speaking' : speakers,
                                 'Fees' : fees, 'Attenders and Trackers': at_tr})
    df.to_excel(file, header=True, index=False) #print the data in the excel sheet. 

    logging.basicConfig(filename = 'error_' + str(time.time()) + '.log', level = logging.INFO)
    logging.info('%d events were read from the excel sheet', len(prev_links))
    logging.info('%d events were added to the excel sheet', len(links) - len(prev_links))
    logging.info('Following are the links of the events that were updated:')
    for item in update:
        logging.info(item)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main() #if the name is main, run the main method and continue with the program.
```

I need all of this functionality done in MongoDB rather than in Excel. I am totally new to MongoDB, so I am not understanding any step to help myself out in the same.

Any help would be awesome. 
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use some sort of mongo API for python, like:
https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/master/README.rst

If you don't know anything about mongo at all, begin with basic tutorial, then use the API to write the values to your database:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_tutorial.pdf